# Java Interface vs Class as return type

Tags: java, class

Let's say we've got inner class (rest of the code isn't really important I guess, `DataStructureIterator` is just the interface extended by `java.util.Iterator<Integer>`):

`private class EvenIterator implements DataStructureIterator`.

Now we want to create a method returning new instance of EvenIterator. As I noticed we can do it in various ways:

1. `public EvenIterator getEvenIterator(){return new EvenIterator();}`
2. `public DataStructureIterator getEvenIterator() {return new EvenIterator();}`

I found out that both versions of the code compiles well, but I just can't get what's the difference (if there's any) between them and which version should be used.

Comment: This is a core principle of OOP. You can find books, blog posts, videos and more answering this question in more detail than you could ever wish for. Try searching "polymorphism".

Comment: @Sam I am learning from the oracle tutorial and the polymorphism part wasn't yet, so as I was analyzing examples I couldn't get it. I will read about it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends. If your method contract is such that you're saying that you're returning some kind of iterator (i.e., not a specific implementation), then return the interface. In other words, your contract is saying "don't assume any other behavior/functionality other than the ability to iterate over integers". The advantage here is that you can then swap out the underlying implementation for something else later. Callers don't and should not care.

On the other hand, if your method's contract is that you return an iterator that *specifically* provides the ability to iterate only over even integers, return `EvenIterator`. This necessarily means you cannot swap out the implementation (to something that doesn't iterate over even integers), and doing so implies breaking/changing the contract. You could abstract further and make `EvenIterator` an interface itself and provide different implementations for the iterator (perhaps one iterates over an internal linked-list, another over an internal array, or perhaps you provide the ability to iterate over specific kinds of even integers; e.g., powers of 2 vs. powers or 4).

Comment: In both cases the return statement is `new EvenIterator()`. Defining the return type as interface <- does it mean that we actual do not return class but just cut from functions (methods of class) interface which can just iterate ? As returning `new EvenIterator()` I though that return type has to be same, but as the example shows it has to be interface, right?

Comment: The interface return-type works because `EvenIterator` implements the interface. I'm not sure what you mean by "cut from functions (methods of class)"; the actual instance itself will be returned. It's just that from the perspective of the calling code, if the return type is the interface, it cannot assume anything more about the return value than what is specified the interface, because that is the method's return type. For example, you cannot call a public method that is only defined on `EvenIterator`, because it is not part of the interface.

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I meant. I wrote some code and indeed it works like that.